# ampersand '&' operator at end of parameter

Tags: c++, boost, reference, operator-keyword, ampersand

I am a noob and this is my first post.

With regards to the '&' character, I understand its general usage as a reference, address and logical operator,...

However, as I was trying to get the boost random number generator functions to work, I noticed another usage of the '&' character I have not seen before... nor is there explicit documentation about it(on the web at least).

Notice below the '&' comes at the END OF parameter mt19937&.

```
boost::variate_generator<boost::mt19937&, boost::uniform_int<> > die(gen, dist);
```

What is this? I am assuming it is being used as a reference somehow, but if I try to put the '&' at the front of the parameter, the compiler says it is unacceptable.

Any explanation would be appreciated.

NK.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the ampersand for when used after class name like ostream& operator <<(...)?](//stackoverflow.com/questions/1572016/90527)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An ampersand before a variable gives you the address of that variable

```
int a = 3;
std::cout << &a << std::endl; // 0x12345678 or similar
```

An ampersand after a type makes that a reference type

```
int& b = a;
std::cout << b << std::endl; // 3
a = 4;
std::cout << b << std::endl; // 4
```

`boost::mt19937` is a type, so `boost::mt19937&` is a reference type to `boost::mt19937`.  Putting the ampersand before (`&boost::mt19937`) doesn't make sense because you cannot get the address of a type.

Comment: Thanks David for your speedy reply.
That makes sense... I was mistaken in thinking that boost::mt19937 was a kind of variable, not a type. Given that boost::mt19937 is a type, that makes sense... cheers.

Comment: So, to research some more on this, I think I need to study Templates... as passing TYPE as an argument